# php to freeze before committing transaction?

Tags: php, jquery, logging, transactions, commit

I want php to freeze before committing transaction so that I display the update log to the user BEFORE committing the transaction and give the option to continue or roll back.

This is the code that commits the updates to the database:-

```
<?php
include 'submitLogger.php';

// Begin logging
ini_set( "error_log", $logFile );
ini_set( "log_errors", "On" );
ini_set( "display_errors", "Off" );
error_log( "Log file '" . $logFile . "' created" );

// Open the database
.
.

error_log( "Connect OK" );
.
.

error_log( "Transaction started (autocommit OFF)\n" ); 
.
.

error_log( "Processing " . count( $deletes ) . " item(s) marked for deletion..." ); 
.
.


// commit changes
error_log( "Committing changes..." ); 
if ( mysqli_commit( $link ) === false ) {
  mysqli_rollback( $link );
  error_log( "Commit failed. Transaction rolled back." ); 
  $response['error'] = "Could not commit changes. Transaction rolled back.";
} else {
  error_log( "Commit successful!" ); 
  $response['success'] = "Success!";
}

// close DB connection
.
.

// Return result
.
.
```

This is the code that loads the update code above and then displays the logfile, but AFTER the transaction has been committed:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {


  // send AJAX request to perform the updates and begin logging
  $.post(
    '../lib/updateMenu.php', 
    sendData,
    function( response ) {
      // was it successful?
      if ( typeof response.success === 'undefined' ) {
        // no - show alert
        if ( response.error ) {
          alert( response.error );
        }
        console.error( "Amend not successful" );
        console.error( response );
        return;
      }

      // delete the AmendmenuAmendselected program window to force a reload on next click
      $( "#programWindowAmendmenuAmendselected" ).remove();
    },
    "json"
  ).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert( 'Unexpected error: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown );
    console.error( 'Unexpected error during amend: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown );
    console.error(jqXHR);
  }).complete(function() {
    // once a reply is received, stop the logging
    ajaxLogtail.stopTail();      
  });

  // begin querying log file
  var ajaxLogtail = new AjaxLogtail( '../lib/ajaxLogtail.php?logfile=' + logFile, "programWindowAmendmenuSubmit" );  
  ajaxLogtail.startTail();
});

</script>
```

How can I tell the php code to wait for a response from the front end before it commits the transaction?

Does anyone have a neat idea to help, please?

Comment: not possible. that's NOT how http works. you can't "freeze" php and then resume, nor can you do the multiple roundtrips between client<->server in a single http request  that a user prompt would require

Comment: @Marc B, can I run the transaction twice? First time as a decoy to show user the log and the second time for real, without the log if the user elects to? Very messy, any neat way to do this?

Comment: not really. when a php script exits, cleanup is performed and your db connection will be closed and the transactions rolled back. If you try using persistent DB connections, there's no guarantee that the response from the user would get the same connection, and you'd end up with a completely different connection which doesn't have te transaction waiting in it.

Answer (score 0):

Since this isn't possible the way you are currently attempting it, I will give you a work around to how I would solve the problem.

I would have my script run an external process, or rather a persistent process or worker (gearman for instance).  It would be the worker that would create the transaction and return a response to my main script to give feedback to the user.

The worker instance would need to be recorded so it can be continued later.  When the user confirms, the next execution of the request would reconnect to the worker telling it to either commit or rollback.

A worm to watch out for though is the life expectancy of the transaction, if the user waits too long, the connection to the database may close.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I want to do @Flosculus. Can you give me a good link to see how set up this worker or should I just google "gearman"?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php The implementation I suggested is not as simple as it sounds unless you are familiar with the concept.  Try out gearman, don't try to implement this yet, just practice playing with the RPC aspect on the program, then you will get the idea of how to get what you need.

Comment: I've done some investigating and gearman is not going to work for a least two reasons: 1. it's a php to php architecture and 2. my updates etc are random and cannot be defined in a job as such. But thanks for the info @Flosculus

Comment: PHP connects to gearman, so you run PHP in command line, that script opens a connection to gearman and waits.  Other scripts then connect to gearman and request a job to be completed.  Its all PHP, gearman is just a message proxy of sorts.